# Is voltage just the energy created from the separation of charges?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, potential-energy, voltage

Recently learnt some physics, and I just want to check my understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes indeed.

- **Electric potential energy** $U_e$ is the potential energy stored when charges are out of equilibrium (like gravitational potential energy when an object is lifted above the ground).
- **Electric potential** is the same, but *per charge*, $\frac{U_e}q$. (Useful when comparing different points.)
- An **electric potential difference** between two points is called **voltage**, $V=\frac{U_{e2} }q-\frac{U_{e1}} q$.

Voltage is a measure of the tendency of charges to move. If a charge is alone, then it has no tendency to move at all (there is no electric force pushing or pulling). If two charges are together, then their electric forces create a potential energy that depends on separation distance (just like the gravitational potential energy between a vase and the ground depends on how high up it has been placed).

Comment: thanks so much, this is very helpful!